# Transfer data from temp table to physical table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table named **`table1`**

```
id   uniquefield    field1        field2
1     11            test          test2
2     12            test2         test3
```

and I have this value in my temp table **`#temp1`**

```
id   uniquefield    field1        field2
1     11            test          test2
2     12            test2         test3
3     13            test4         test5
4     14            test5         test6
```

Now, what I want to happen is that I want to transfer all data from `#temp1` table. It would insert if data does not exist in table1 table and would update if it exist.

Does anybody know how to do this using SQL Server or dynamic SQL?

Hope to find some response from you.

Comment: It could be done with one [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement.

Comment: Will the matching to see if row exists be done on id or uniquefield column ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temp tables are no different in such cases like you mentioned. The difference is they are only available to the current connection for the user; and they are automatically deleted when the user disconnects from instances. So you can handle these tables like any other SQL table and use a MERGE query to achieve this data manupulation.

Assuming the uniquefield column can be treated as link between these tables.

```
MERGE table1 t
USING #temp1 t1
ON t.uniquefield = t1.uniquefield
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET t.id = t1.id,
t.field1 = t1.field1,
t.field2 = t1.field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
  INSERT (id, uniquefield, field1, field2)
  VALUES (t1.id, t1.uniquefield, t1.field1, t1.field2 );
```

You can `DROP #temp1` after this and do a `SELECT * FROM table1` to check the updated/ inserted data.

Answer (score 2):

`Temp tables` are no different in such cases like you mentioned. The difference is they are only available to the current connection for the user; and they are automatically deleted when the user disconnects from instances. So you can handle these tables like any other SQL table.

Assuming the `uniquefield` column can be treated as link between these tables.

Update statemant:

```
update table1
set
t.id = t1.id,
t.field1 = t1.field1,
t.field2 = t1.field2
from table1 t
join #temp1 t1
on t.uniquefield = t1.uniquefield
```

Insert statement:

```
insert into table1(id, uniquefield, field1, field2)
select t1.id, t1.uniquefield, t1.field1, t1.field2 
from table1 t
join #temp1 t1
on t.uniquefield != t1.uniquefield
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume 2 table row is identical by `id`, insert with not `exists()`

```
-- Append missing row to table1
INSERT table1 
SELECT * FROM #temp1 t WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = t.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming that `id` is the table primary key. Otherwise replace appropriately.

```
UPDATE Table1
SET id= T.id,
    Uniquefield = T.Uniquefield,
    Field1 = T.field1,
    Field2 = T.field2
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN #temp1 T ON T.id = Table1.id;

INSERT INTO Table1 (id, uniquefield, field1, field2)
SELECT id, uniquefield, field1, field2
FROM #temp1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table1)
```

Comment: If datas are not changed then also why updation ?

Comment: That's because checking all fields before update is usually a waste of time and efforts and doesn't affect the results. My personal views :)

Comment: Here we have just 4 fields, so it might be easy to check for changes. But assume for example the table had 50 columns. Checking for changes in such cases might not be worth it; doing a blind update would be quicker as well as less code to handle. Now you get the point?

Comment: I included Update because I am thinking that users will update the table in which the #temp table get its data. So instead inserting all data to table1 I would like to update it if it already exists. :)

Comment: Yes the code does the same - update if exists otherwisr insert. My earlier  comments were in response to @utility 's question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the elegant way is to use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) here:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON;

MERGE INTO table1 AS T
USING #temp1 AS S 
     ON S.id = T.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET
        T.uniquefield = S.uniquefield,
        T.field1 = S.field1,
        T.field2 = S.field2
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (id, uniquefield, field1, field2)
    VALUES (S.id, S.uniquefield, S.field1, S.field2);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF;
```

I have added the IDENTITY_INSERT there just in case ID column in your table1 is an IDENTITY and you might want to keep the one from #temp1 table. If you dont need / have IDENTITY, just remove those lines.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this query:-

```
 insert  into table1

 select * from (

 select    #temp.workersID,#temp.W_name,#temp.salary,#temp.joining_year,#temp.city,#temp.id 
  from #temp

  full join workers

  on #temp.WorkersID = workers.WorkersID

  where workers.WorkersID is null

  ) ds
```